# How to top, left justify text in a <td> cell that spans multiple rows

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Save a lot</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using CSS styling or another method, can I make the text "Save a lot" top, left justified?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
td[rowspan] {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}
```

See: [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).

Comment: except for the IE Bug (6/7/8).. for IE you need to be specific about the rows spanned, in this case  `td[rowspan="2"]` - apparently the DTD **default** setting `<td rowspan="1">` is considered to match `td[rowspan]` even when not explicitly specified, so it effectively matches **ALL** `td`'s - whether it should or not is another matter, and this also applies to `colspan` - [the long story](http://www.highdots.com/forums/cascading-style-sheets/re-tables-colspan-298379.html)

Answer (score 10):

```
 <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0">Save a lot</td>
```

That should do it.

Comment: Note this will not work if you want to vertical-align:bottom as it aligns to the row next to it, not to the bottom of the two-row cell

Answer (score 4):

try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:50%;">
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:100px">
      <td valign="top">January</td>
      <td valign="bottom">$100</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

use valign="top" for td style

Comment: "valign" attribute is not longer supported in HTML5. Use CSS "vertical-align" e.g. vertical-align: top; or vertical-align: bottom;